# How to use select chosen?

Tags: html, jquery-chosen

I have this row in table

```
<td class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="width: 100%" title="">
    <a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1">
        <span>Choose a country...</span>
        <div><b></b></div>
    </a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <div class="chosen-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" />
        </div>
        <select class="chosen-results">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">United States</option>
            <option class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">United Kingdom</option>
            <option class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Afghanistan</option>
            <option class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">Aland Islands</option>
            <option class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5">Albania</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

Whats wrong with this code? I need to realize standart chosen select.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the chosen option to appear in the text box?

Comment: I need to create standart chosen select on my page

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear to me what you mean by "create standart chosen select". Please elaborate more

Comment: As Ahs N said we are not clear as to what you want. So can you be more specific.

Comment: I need to create this https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: As per specifed in the setup procedure, have you downloaded the plugin and activated it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q8buLh7/2/)

```
<option value="" class="placeholder">select</option>
```